# How to clear TreeViewItem's Parent property?

Tags: c#

How to clear `System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem`'s Parent property? Its read-only and I cant add same TreeViewItem to different TreeViews:

```
TreeView1.Items.Add(MyTreeViewItem);   // Sucess!
TreeView2.Items.Add(MyTreeViewItem);   // Error (MyTreeViewItem alredy has parent - TreeView1)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Well, this TreeView is the one in PresentationFramework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well judging by the error you can't have the same node in two different trees (not totally unreasonable).

You can either remove the element from the first tree (eg through `TreeView1.Items.Remove(MyTreeViewItem)`) or duplicating the node and adding it to both.

Comment: I'd argue that this is a better answer than the official "answered" question. Using `.Remove` is better than `.Clear` - If you are only ever talking about a single node in the Treeview, then fair enough. But if you want to move one of many nodes then `.Clear` is going to wipe everything out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following methods of `TreeView`. Notice that a *readonly* property only can not be set, its methods like `Clear()` can be called as below:

```
System.Windows.Controls.TreeView treeView = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeView();
System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();

treeView.Items.Clear();
treeView.Items.Contains(item);
treeView.Items.Remove(item);
```

Comment: So easy..Thank you! I tried to do it from another end all this time.